# Terraform: Get Custom Domain Verification Id without an App Service

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In Azure, the Custom Domain Verification Id is unique across a subscription.

Using Terraform, I can get the customDomainVerificationId from an existing AppService...

```
${azurerm_windows_web_app.myappservice.custom_domain_verification_id}
```

...but is there a way to obtain this value (so I can set up asuid in a dns zone) without an app service existing (perhaps from the subscription)?

Is this possible using Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear, at this time, it is not possible.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14142

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Domain Verification ID is shared across a subscription. But it seems like at least one app service needs to be created before it's available.

When available the following two-ways (mentioned in the GH issue) works without having to reference an app service directly.

`az extension add --name resource-graph`

1. `az graph query -q "Resources | project name, properties.customDomainVerificationId, type | where type == 'microsoft.web/sites'"`
2. `az graph query -q "Resources | join kind=leftouter (ResourceContainers | where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project SubName=name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId | where  type == 'microsoft.web/sites'| project vid = tostring(properties.customDomainVerificationId), SubName | distinct *"`

The other method of verification (also mentioned in the GH issue below) is adding a `awverify` record.

`CNAME or TXT awverify.yourdns.com => awverify.your-web-app-name.azurewebsites.net`

Because you will be specifying `your-web-app-name` this record can be blindly created ahead of time.

source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14142